# jQuery and PHP session checking

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have an app that uses jQuery on the front and PHP in the back. If the PHP session expires then the app will do weird things if the user tries to interact with it. As such, I want to check periodically to ensure the PHP session is still set and if not, prompt the user to re-login before they can do anything.

So, my question is the following: If I send an ajax post every 10 seconds that checks if a specific PHP session variable isset, is that overkill? Basically, I'm sending a request with ajax to a php page that looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// CHECK FOR SESSION
if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
    $response = 'true';
} else {
    $response = 'false';    
}

// ECHO RESPONSE
echo "<response>\n";
echo "\t<row>\n";
echo "\t\t<valid>".$response."</valid>\n";
echo "\t</row>\n";
echo "</response>\n";
?>
```

I then parse the result.

Can someone suggest a lighter approach? Or is there anything wrong with I'm doing?

Comment: I personally wouldn't say this was overkill, what with websites like Facebook now, sending god knows how many ajax requests. Though they do encode their return content to lower the size. It all depends on the spec/speed of your server/connection. It also uses something called [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to push data from the server to the client, without polling.

Answer (score 1):

What is the 'weird things' when somebody tries to interact with the app if the session is expired? Is it because it also fetches data from the server and it doesn't get the correct data because the session expired?

If so, you could let the server send back a certain response if the session expired and check that in javascript. For example you could have the response send back a json with as first key `session` which is a boolean indicating if the session is still valid and as second key `data` which holds the originally requested data when the session is still valid.

When you use this approach, you won't have to check every 10 seconds, you can just respond appropriately as soon as you detect the session expired.